# Image of point of codimension one has codimension one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm working on the following exercise (7.2.3) from Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*:

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of Noetherian schemes. We suppose that either $f$ is flat or $X,Y$ are integral and $f$ is finite surjective.
>   Let $x \in X$ be a point of codimension $1$, and $y = f(x)$. Show that $\dim \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} = 1$ if $f$ is finite surjective...

Is this statement true? The going-up theorem only shows that $\dim V(y) = \dim V(x)$, which is not the same thing, since it is not always true that $\dim V(y) + \dim \mathcal{O_{Y,y}} = \dim Y$. It seems to me like we need the going-down theorem, which requires an additional normality hypothesis on $Y$. I think the problem is that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is not necessarily finite.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true. There is a famous example of Nagata of a Noetherian local domain $A$ of dimension $2$ which has a finite overring $A \subset B$ with two maximal ideals $\mathfrak m, \mathfrak n \subset B$ with $\dim(B_{\mathfrak m}) = 2$ and $\dim(B_{\mathfrak n}) = 1$. Let $X$ be the spectrum of $B$ and $Y$ be the spectrum of $A$ and let $x$ be the point corresponding to the prime ideal $\mathfrak n$.

The example can be found in Appendix, Example 2 of Nagata's book ``Local rings'' published in 1962. See also [Tag 02JE](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JE).

Comment: wow, it seems whenever there's a crazy example of nasty Noetherian rings, it has Nagata's name somewhere nearby!

Two questions: first, is the dimension of $B_\mathfrak{m}$ supposed to be $2$? Otherwise, I don't see how $B$ could have dimension $2$.

Second, it seems like this example is intimately tied to the property of being "universally catenary". Does the statement in the exercise hold if $X$ is catenary?

Comment: Thanks for the correction! The statement holds if $Y$ is universally catenarry, by the dimension formula, see http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JU.